# Autofac Lifetime scopes with external application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, ioc-container, unit-of-work

It'll probably take a few more questions to understand this subject quite well. 
I've read a lot of documentations, yet I can't figure it out completely.

Say for example :

**Singleton1** = resolved in **lifetimeScope1**

Singleton1 handles messages coming from **Tcp/Ip**. 
DataService handles messages coming from web controllers, and it handles messages from Singleton1 (meaning - messages from Tcp/Ip).

In DataService there is a component registered as PerLifetimeScope (DbContext).

The things I can't understand is:

1. How will DataService  know if it currently handles Http request (and should use instance 1 of DbContext) or Tcp/Ip (and use instance 2 of DbContext)?

My final goal is to configure Autofac to create me a new lifetime scope for each Tcp/Ip request I get as well. Just like it automatically does with Http requests!

**Note:**

If it'll be easier to understand with code, I'll put it, I just thought it could complicate things.

If anything I said was stupid or incorrect please fix me. Having hard time learning this.

Thanks!

**Edit**:

Adding code to explain my problem better:

```
public class Singleton1 : ISingleton1
{
    private IDataService _dataService;

    public Singleton1(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
    }

    public void HandleExternalAddItemMessage(AddItemMessage msg)
    {
        _dataService.AddItem(msg.Item);
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();
}

public EFUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _context;


    public EFUnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class DataService
{
    private Func<Owned<IUnitOfWork>> _unitOfWorkFactory;

    public (Func<Owned<IUnitOfWork>> unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;             
    }

    // This method is called from both controllers and  external Tcp/Ip calls. How do I do it - how do I set the context that is in the unit of work???
    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        using(unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkFactory())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}


Startup code:

{
    _container.RegisterType<IDataService, DataService>().SingleInstance();
    _container.RegisterType<Singleton1, ISingleton1>().SingleInstance();
    _container.RegisterType<EFUnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork>().PerDepnendecny();
    _container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

}
```

Comment: 1. Singletons sit outside of any lifetime scope. 2. If a singleton references a component with a shorter lifetime you have a [captive dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: Do you know of way to accomplish my goal? Treat each Tcp/Ip message like autofac treats http requests - get each of them in a new lifetime scope

Comment: Register your components as `InstancePerLifetimeScope`.

Comment: I think some code would be useful, if you could paste it here

Comment: The singletons must be singletons

Comment: Added code to the question

Answer (score 0):

This is a great article by Nicholas Blumhardt touching on many issues surrounding object lifetime including common pitfalls by developers attempting to own the object disposal in Autofac.

http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/

I think what you're attempting to do is probably overly complicated and the model can probably be simplified however it is possible to register a new instance of an object by manually creating your own `LifetimeScope`.

```
public class Singleton1 : ISingleton1
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public Singleton1(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    public void HandleExternalAddItemMessage(AddItemMessage msg)
    {
        using(var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var dataService = scope.Resolve<IDataService>();
            dataService.AddItem(msg.Item);
        }
    }
}
```

As the article will explain you're now brewing up a nice batch of "scope soup".

Pay close attention to **Nested lifetime scopes** and **Scope Sharing**. Your usage of singletons is likely to trip you up.

Comment: Thanks alot for your great answer, will take a look. I don't think what I'm trying to acheive it too complicated, I think it's even pretty common yet I haven't find a proper solution. I just want a unit of work factory for creating entity framework transactions inside of a singleton.